# Get pdf file provided by webapp

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to download multiple pdf files of old newspapers. Specifically files that look like [this](https://www.sbt.ti.ch/quotidiani-public-pdf/web/viewer.html?file=%2Faqp_pdf%2Fgdp%2F2005%2F12%2Fgdp_2005-12-01%2Fgdp_2005-12-01_001.pdf) or [this](https://www.sbt.ti.ch/quotidiani-public-pdf/left_side.php?paper=gdp&year=2005&month=12&day=1). My problem is that when I try to automate this process with `requests` or `wget`, because the sites don't give you an actual pdf file, I am not able to get the actual file.

Is there a way to automate this process and download the actual files with Python?

Comment: there *may* be an api.  But have a look at [the url of the direct link](https://www.sbt.ti.ch/quotidiani-public-pdf/main_part.php?fullscreen=true&paper=gdp&day=1&month=12&year=2005&page=1&allpages=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28&papername=Giornale%20del%20Popolo) for the second link you provided.  It looks pretty easy to construct that url programatically, right?

Comment: @2e0byo that's correct, but because that is a web app where the link for the pdf is provided as an argument. So I end up downloading the html or php file.

Comment: `pdf.js` renders pdf pages, so you could download the [individual pages](https://www.sbt.ti.ch/aqp_pdf/gdp/2005/12/gdp_2005-12-01/gdp_2005-12-01_001.pdf) and stitch them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular web page the pages are served from a predictable url:

- https://www.sbt.ti.ch/aqp_pdf/gdp/2005/12/gdp_2005-12-01/gdp_2005-12-01_001.pdf
- https://www.sbt.ti.ch/aqp_pdf/gdp/2005/12/gdp_2005-12-01/gdp_2005-12-01_002.pdf
- etc

This is so regular I wouldn't even bother extracting it from the page for this problem: I'd just generate the url myself, do a `requests.get()` for each of them, and splice them together with `PyPdf2`.

The more general question is: how did I know that url?  Have a look at your browser's devtools:

[image]

## General approaches

There are basically two solutions to this kind of problem:

- extract the required parameters from the page (look at how the page builds up the urls it needs), or
- run a real browser with something like selenium, and automate it.

Sometimes you get lucky and there's a real api designed to help you do this.  It's quite common when looking at public archive data like this (in France, the apis of the BNF are excellent, but I don't know what, if anything, would be the Italian equivalent).